# Trigger a payable function to send ipfsHash back to sender

Tags: ipfs, payable

I want to make a testnetwork, a supply chain, with 10 manufacturers/addresses. For that I want to make a function that sends the saved ipfsHash, which is the information about the product that will be send to the manufacturer, back to the sender when the function receives a certain payment.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'd suggest following the Cryptozombies tutorial to learn the basics of Solidity, what you are describing is definitely doable: https://cryptozombies.io/en/course/

Comment: One thing to consider is whether you would prefer for payments to be made in Ether or using a stablecoin such as DAI. :)

Comment: @Jay Yes, I also already thought about that to have a stable price :) But thanks for the advice. Thank you I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm ... I might suggest a little consideration of the business model.

The first thing that springs to mind is the inherent challenge of keeping a secret on the Ethereum blockchain. It's optimized for transparency - roughly the opposite of confidentiality. In practice, that means that *all* data stored on the network is knowable by *all* interested parties at *all* times.

I'm not suggesting that is insurmountable but it is nontrivial if revealing the information is meant to be linked to a financial transaction.

> information about the product

It seems somewhat odd that informative information, like a brochure, would have a cost associated with it. However, it might be worthwhile to research projects that are pursuing digital rights management for insights into innovations. Given the challenge mentioned above, I suspect you will find there are more moving parts than you might initially expect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: To be more precise I want to have informations about the CO2, water and energycosts linked to the product or the part of the product and the costs. So in the end you will be able to make a more accurate life cycle inventory out of it. So it should be transparent in my opinion.

Comment: If you want the information open then the name of the game is access control and provenance. You create a contract that allows a privileged signer to maintain a list of products and datasheet urls/hashes. Whomever writes the list of record (the contract) pays a small amount of gas to put information there, but everyone else browses for free.

Comment: I get what you say. But I imagine this as a system that every company would have to implement in their supply chain. I think the gas costs should be quite low if you only save the ipfshash. I don't know if anyone would have an advantage to see the data of the others, because you would have to calculate the life cycle assessment(LCA) first. The idea is that once you calculate the LCA out of the data you would be able to compare the parts of similar supply chains and then you could improve them. Companies would eventually be able to save costs and also emit fewer pollutants...

Comment: ...But I'm not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: We dont have enough information about the business model to hint at solving all the problems. My answer was about the platform constraints to think about.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll keep it in mind.